# Generate random Byte Array without ignored values

Tags: c#, arrays, random

This is the code I use to generate random bytes array. It is perfectly OK, the only thing is
there's a number (or numbers) I don't want. My question is, how can I ensure that, this unwanted number(s) is not included in the results, without having to go through each result?

```
    Random rnd = new Random();
    Byte[] bytes = new Byte[50];
    rnd.NextBytes(bytes);
```

For a byte I use this function;

```
    int b = rnd.Next(min, (max + 1))
    return (byte) b;
```

where I can control the result range, but repeated calls to this function will not give a good results.

Comment: What numbers is it you do not want? Can you show a sample output that contains such numbers, and also what you would expect it to look like instead?

Comment: " but repeated calls to this function will not give a good results." what does this mean? Are you getting the same number every time you call the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem can be easily solved with a Monte Carlo algorithm. This is what @SteveLillis is going on about, but it's an incomplete answer. So here is it in full.

```
void Main()
{
    var exclusions = new HashSet<byte> { 1, 200, 58, 11, 66, 9 };

    var results = RandomBytes()
                    .Where(b => exclusions.Contains(b) == false)
                    .Take(50)
                    .ToArray();
}

public IEnumerable<byte> RandomBytes()
{
    var random = new Random();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
    while(true)
    {
        random.NextBytes(buffer);
        foreach(var ret in buffer)
        {
            yield return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

`RandomBytes()` is a stream of random bytes, pretty simple right?

Then we exclude anything from the stream that we don't like, with `Where(b => exclusions.Contains(b) == false)`. The hashset is for "efficiency", but it doesn't help with `byte` (just put it in due to habit).

`Take(50)`, we only want 50 from the stream.

`ToArray` give me the results as an array.

Comment: yield and lambda... COOL @Aron!!! But I don't understand why 32 for the buffer array? a 1 array is good enough since it is a random number, don't you think so?

Comment: @sambyte I am not entirely sure what the implementation of `.NextBytes` is. In general, when they expose functionality in such a way, its usually cheaper to run with a "largish" buffer. But yes...functionally, `byte[1]` would work exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not too likely that the number will keep coming up, you can just keep trying until a 'good' number is generated.

```
var badNumbers = new int[] { 244, 100 };
int b = 0;
do
{
    b = rnd.Next(min, (max + 1));
} while (badNumbers.Contains(b));
```

Also, make sure you declare your Random object and use it over and over, don't keep instantiating a new one, as by default the seed is taken from time and if you instantiate two randoms too quickly one after the other, they'll generate the same number.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate allowable values in the separate array (in respect to the min value, the max value, and the ignored values) and use it for target array generation. Let's consider the following example.

Help functions:

```
byte[] GenerateAllowableValues(byte min, byte max, byte[] ignore)
{
  var list = new List<byte>();
  for (byte i = min; i <= max; i++)
    if (!ignore.Contains(i))
      list.Add(i);
  return list.ToArray();
}

byte[] GenerateRandomArray(Random random, byte[] allowableValues, int length)
{ 
  var array = new byte[length];
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    array[i] = allowableValues[random.Next(allowableValues.Length)];
  return array;
}
```

Usage:

```
void Main()
{
  var random = new Random(42);
  var allowableValues = GenerateAllowableValues(10, 20, new byte[] { 12, 15 });
  var randomArray = GenerateRandomArray(random, allowableValues, 5);
  foreach (byte b in randomArray)
    Console.WriteLine(b); // 18 11 11 16 11
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Construct an array of the bytes you want excluding the ones you do not, then pick a random element from that array 50 times;

```
var rnd = new Random();
var exclusions = new byte[] { 1, 200, 58, 11, 66, 9 };
var candidates = Enumerable.Range(0, 255).Where(i => !exclusions.Contains((byte)i)).ToArray();

var results = new byte[50];
for (var i = 0; i < results.Length; i++)
{
    results[i] = (byte)candidates[rnd.Next(0, candidates.Length - 1)];
}
```